# Custom event only fired single eventsubscriber, if in a AdvancedQueueJob, but all if fired from module

Tags: event-subscribers

I have a custom event in my commerce 2 shop.

filename: custom_module/src/Event/OrderShippedEvent.php

```
namespace Drupal\custom_module\Event;

class OrderShippedEvent extends EventBase
{
  public const EVENT_NAME = 'custom_events.order_shipped';

  /**
   * @var \Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\OrderInterface
   */
  protected OrderInterface $order;

  protected RequestStack $requestStack;

  public function __construct(OrderInterface $order)
  {
    $this->order = $order;
    $this->requestStack = \Drupal::service('request_stack');
  }
```

And a eventsubscriber

filename: custom_module/src/EventSubscriber/OrderShippedSubscriber.php

```php
class OrderShippedSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

  /**
   * The log storage.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\commerce_log\LogStorageInterface
   */
  protected $logStorage;

  public function __construct(
    protected RequestStack $stack,
    protected EntityTypeManagerInterface $entityTypeManager)
  {
    $this->logStorage = $entityTypeManager->getStorage('commerce_log');
  }

  public static function getSubscribedEvents()
  {
    $events[OrderShippedEvent::EVENT_NAME][] = ['onOrderShipped', 100];

    return $events;
  }

  public function onOrderShipped(OrderShippedEvent $event): void
  {
    $order = $event->getOrder();

    // Do some magic to the order 
  }
```

My modules services.yml file contains this

```yaml
  custom_events.order_shipped:
    class: Drupal\custom_module\EventSubscriber\OrderShippedSubscriber
    arguments: [ '@request_stack', '@entity_type.manager' ]
    tags:
      - { name: 'event_subscriber' }
```

And more on that, i'm using the https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_email module, to send mail when this event is fired.

filename: custom_module/src/Plugin/Commerce/EmailEvent/OrderShippedEvent.php

```php
/**
 * @CommerceEmailEvent(
 *    id = "order_shipped_notification",
 *    label = @Translation("Order Shipped"),
 *    event_name = "custom_events.order_shipped",
 *    entity_type = "commerce_order",
 *   priority = "-100"
 *  )
 */
class OrderShippedEvent extends EmailEventBase
{

  public function extractEntityFromEvent(Event $event)
  {
    return $event->getOrder();
  }

}
```

From a custom AdvancedQueueJob i try to trigger the event so the magic is happening to the order, and an email is sent.

Only "magic happens" no mail was sent.

If i use the exact code from a .module file both is fired

filename: another_module.module

```php
function another_module_page_attachments(array &$attachments) {
  // hardcoded to test a single order.
  $order = \Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\Order::load(54);
  $event = new OrderShippedEvent($order);
  /** @var \Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher $event_dispatcher */
  $event_dispatcher = \Drupal::service('event_dispatcher');
  $event_dispatcher->dispatch($event, OrderShippedEvent::EVENT_NAME);
}
```

The codesnippet i use to test is

```php
  // hardcoded to test a single order.
  $order = \Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\Order::load(54);
  $event = new OrderShippedEvent($order);
  /** @var \Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher $event_dispatcher */
  $event_dispatcher = \Drupal::service('event_dispatcher');
  $event_dispatcher->dispatch($event, OrderShippedEvent::EVENT_NAME);
```

And from the Advancedqueuejob only the magic to the order event is fired.

I have tried almost everything, hope you guys can help me out here.

Comment: More to the question: when used from module i'm authenticated, and from a advancedqueuejob im running from Drush ?

Comment: And if fired from cron UI it works, but not from drush advancedqueue:process queuename

Comment: It's because KernelEvent:REQUEST isn't fired from drush